# Updating an Object's property in a Vector

Tags: c++, object, c++11, vector, updates

I have a vector which contains objects. The objects have a property called first name. I want to update the first name in a property, in order to do that i have to pass the vector which the objects are saved, staff number which uniquely identifies each object and finally the new name taken from the user input.

My problem is it displays the update name in the loop which i use to set the new name but if i use a second loop or a new loop and iterate through the vector again, the new name isn't saved but the old name is displayed.

Here is what i have done :-

```
public: void updateFirstName(vector<Administrator> vectorUpdate,string staffNumber,string newName)
{
    FileHandler<Administrator> adminTObj;
    for(Administrator iter: vectorUpdate)
    {
    if(iter.getStaffNumber()==staffNumber)
        {
        iter.setFirstName(newName);
        cout<<"Update"<<endl;

        cout<<iter.getFirstName()<<endl;
                    //here it prints the updated name but if i use a different loop 
                   //and iterate through the vector the new name is not saved.
        }
    }   

}
```

What seems to be the problem here ? Thank you

Comment: `iter` is a *copy* of the object in the vector.

Comment: Write the `for` as `for(Administrator& iter: vectorUpdate)`

Comment: For that matter, so too is the passed vector itself. Hard telling if that is intentional or not.

Comment: @WhozCraig is right, you probably want to pass the whole `vectorUpdate` by reference in the function, otherwise you don't modify it at the exit of the function, you just modify a copy.

Comment: *Both* issues should be resolved if the intention is for that to be in in/out param.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass a vector by value

```
void updateFirstName(vector<Administrator> vectorUpdate,
                                        string staffNumber,string newName)
```

so each time you call this function you will copy original vector into it and work on this copied vector inside the function. The result of this is the changes are made to local variable inside function. Instead you want to pass vector by reference:

```
void updateFirstName( vector<Administrator> &vectorUpdate,
                                        string staffNumber,string newName)
```

In function body, here

```
for( Administrator iter: vectorUpdate)
```

you will experienced the same thing. You want to write:

```
for( Administrator& iter: vectorUpdate)
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought vectors were like arrays or array lists, so i thought they were passed by reference. I am not very familiar with vectors. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: It's not just this, the iterator itself must be a reference!

Comment: @vsoftco I've mentioned this too

Comment: @Shehan.W no, they are very different though they are written in hope to provide dynamic arrays, you should read about vector definitely - it is one of the most important containers. For STL containers you should use them by default if you cannot point out any particular reason for using something else.