# Properly Store Object in Vector

Tags: c++, object, vector

I'm brand new to C++, and this is my first time posting (recipe for disaster). I've spent about a day trying to resolve my problem/question, in the mean time finding no easily recognizable solution on the forums. It's possible that my question has already been asked or that a solution has already been posted but I've overlooked it or misunderstood it. A similar post exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848343/updating-an-objects-property-in-a-vector), but it's not obvious to me what to do with the information.

I'll provide a concise, high-level summary of the point of this code. I'll then ask the specific question(s) to which I'm unable to find an answer, and I'll follow with the code I've written.

SUMMARY: I'm creating a program to help do bookkeeping for a game. The game may have any number of players, and each player having a small list of attributes/members (e.g. playerName, playerAllegiance, etc.) which are elements of a Player class/object. The user is first asked to input the name of each player (enteredName), and the program must create a new Player object for each name that's entered. This seems to be appropriately handled by a dynamic array, so I chose to use a vector (called playerIndex) to store each Player object. A for-loop allows the user to input names, each name instantiating a new Player object which is to be stored (copied?) into playerIndex using vector::push_back. At the conclusion of the for-loop, the user should be left with a vector of Player objects, each Player object storing a name in its playerName member.

QUESTION/PROBLEM: The code seems to work proprly when monitoring the vector inside the aforementioned for-loop. Immediately after the user enters the Nth player's name, the program spits out the playerName string stored in the Nth element of playerIndex using a Player class function getPlayerName() [actual code: playerIndex[playerCounter].getPlayerName()]. As soon as the user enters a blank playerName (i.e. presses enter without entering a name), it indicates the user has entered all player names, so the for-loop terminates. Just after this loop, a loop which is designed to output the playerName of each Player object stored in playerIndex does not output the expected names. I don't know why this is happening, but based on my very minimal knowledge of constructors, I'm guessing it has something to do with a copy or move constructor for the Player class. Can anyone clearly explain how to handle this issue? I fear I may be making a pitifully stupid, novice mistake and/or misunderstanding a key concept of C++.

CODE: This code is cropped/simplified to be as clear as possible. For example, the Player class is shown to have only one member (playerName) while, in the original code, it has four or five other members.

```
//HeaderPlayerClass.hpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#ifndef PLAYERCLASS_HPP
#define PLAYERCLASS_HPP

using std::string;

class Player {
    private:
        string *playerName;

    public:
        Player();
        Player(string);
        ~Player();
        string getPlayerName();
};

#endif




//PlayerClass.cpp
#include "HeaderPlayerClass.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

Player::Player() {
    playerName = new string;
}

Player::Player(string enteredName) {
    playerName = new string;    
    *playerName = enteredName;
}

Player::~Player() {
    delete playerName;
}

string Player::getPlayerName() {
    return *playerName;
}





//main.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "HeaderPlayerClass.hpp"

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    string buffer;
    vector<Player> playerIndex;

    int playerCounter = 0;

    for(;;) {
        if(playerCounter==0) {
            cout << "\nEnter player name and press enter; leave blank and press enter to continue.\n";
        }

        cout << "\nPlayer " << playerCounter+1 << ":";
        getline(cin, buffer);

        if(buffer == "esc") {
            cout << "PROGRAM EXITED BY USER\n";
            return 0;
        }

        if(buffer.empty()) {
            break;
        }

        playerIndex.push_back(Player(buffer));
        cout << "Player " << playerCounter+1 << "'s name:" << playerIndex[playerCounter].getPlayerName() << "\n";

        ++playerCounter;
    }

    for(int ii = 0 ; ii < playerIndex.size() ; ii++) {
        cout << "\nThis should display player " << ii+1 << "'s name:" << playerIndex[ii].getPlayerName();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Player {
    private:
        string *playerName;
```

Do not store a pointer to the string, store the string itself

```
class Player {
    private:
        string playerName;
```

Constructor

```
Player::Player() {
    playerName = new string;
}
```

This is unnecessary if you store the string itself - the default constructor will initialize it for you.

Here is where the problems start - this will leave you vulnerable to memory leaks unless you carefully write a destructor

```
Player::Player(string enteredName) {
    playerName = new string;    
    *playerName = enteredName;
}
```

All you need, if you store the string itself:

```
Player::Player( const string& enteredName)
: playerName ( enteredName )
{}
```

You constructor is really scary.  Just leave things to the default destructor when you store the string itself

```
Player::~Player() {
    delete playerName;
}
```

Next, you are working too hard keeping your own counter.  std::vector maintains its own count and using

```
playerIndex.size()
```

will save trouble and bugs

Comment: The constructor should use initialization, not assignment. `Player::Player( const string& enteredName) : playerName(enteredName) {}`

Comment: This all makes sense (including list initialization), but I'm still unclear on when it's appropriate to use "new", especially in the context of classes. Suppose enteredName were an int rather than a string; would the constructor need to implement "new int" (similar to what I attempted to do in my posted code) since an int doesn't have a default constructor like a string?

Comment: @roc645 There is no such thing as "new int", so my advice would be not to use it!  Seriously, the initialization of a int is left to the compiler, many but not all will set it to zero.  So, to be safe and portable you will always have to assign a value to an int

Comment: @ravenspoint: Of course there is such a thing as `new int`! It's just that you rarely, or almost never, need it. And it has nothing to do with zero-initialisation; that's an almost orthogonal aspect of the language. Also, assignment and initialization are quite different things. Your advice to the OP is probably good in spirit, but you mix up too many things and the way you describe them, your comment is technically imprecise or wrong.

Comment: @roc645: C++ is certainly a bit difficult with regards to this for a beginner. My advice would be NOT to use dynamic allocation at all until you feel the need for it. In modern C++, this will happen rarely because of all the standard classes which hide all the dynamic allocation in their implementation.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I appreciate the advice. I'm doing a linear read-through of Stroustrup's most recent C++ book. I've also reviewed the tutorial on cplusplus.com a few times. Any additional recommended resources for beginners? What I'm finding confusing is when to know whether the compiler will naturally dynamically allocate memory. Like I said, I think it makes sense in the case of a string, but in the example of the int, I don't see anywhere where an int is dynamically allocated, so I'd be tempted to create a "new" one.